# PHP regex to check if image is wrapped with a tag

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I am creating a wordpress function and need to determine whether an image in the content is wrapped with an a tag that contains a link to a PDF or DOC file e.g.

```
<a href="www.site.com/document.pdf"><img src="../images/image.jpg" /></a>
```

How would I go about doing this with PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml), pick your favorite approach and then analyze all the links you could find in the text. Regular expressions are usually the wrong solution to a parsing problem.

Comment: The <img> and <a> tags are not always exactly as shown, there will be variations since dynamic content is going to be processed. For example there may be a string such as: <p>this is some text <a href="site.com/doc.pdf"> more text</p>

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 2):

I would *very* strongly advise against using a regular expression for this. Besides being more error prone and less readable, it also does not give you the ability to manipulate the content easily.

You would be better of loading the content into a DomDocument, retrieving all `<img>` elements and validating whether or not their parents are `<a>` elements. All you would have to do then is validate whether or not the value of the `href` attribute ends with the desired extension.

A very crude implementation would look a bit like [this](http://ideone.com/mhOHSa):

```
<?php

$sHtml = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
    <img src="../images/image.jpg" />
    <a href="www.site.com/document.pdf"><img src="../images/image.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="www.site.com/document.txt"><img src="../images/image.jpg" /></a>
    <p>this is some text <a href="site.com/doc.pdf"> more text</p> 
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$oDoc = new DOMDocument();
$oDoc->loadHTML($sHtml);
$oNodeList = $oDoc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($oNodeList as $t_oNode)
{
    if($t_oNode->parentNode->nodeName === 'a')
    {
        $sLinkValue = $t_oNode->parentNode->getAttribute('href');
        $sExtension = substr($sLinkValue, strrpos($sLinkValue, '.'));

        echo '<li>I am wrapped in an anchor tag '
           . 'and I link to  a ' . $sExtension . ' file '
        ; 
    }
}
?>
```

I'll leave an exact implementation as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: +1 And you could also add `&& preg_match('/\.(pdf|doc)$/i', $t_oNode->parentNode->getAttribute('href'))` to your `if` statement.

Comment: I feel more inclined to use `strrpos` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DOM parse based code that you can use:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<a href="www.site.com/document.pdf"><img src="../images/image.jpg" /></a>
<img src="../images/image1.jpg" />
<a href="www.site.com/document.txt"><IMG src="../images/image2.jpg" /></a>
<a href="www.site.com/document.doc"><img src="../images/image3.jpg" /></a>
<a href="www.site.com/document1.pdf">My PDF</a>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$nodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
for($i=0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodeList->item($i);
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    $hasImage = false;
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
       if ($child->nodeName == 'img') {
          $hasImage = true;
          break;
       }
    }
    if (!$hasImage)
       continue;
    if ($node->hasAttributes())
       foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
          $name = $attr->nodeName;
          $value = $attr->nodeValue;
          if ($attr->nodeName == 'href' && 
              preg_match('/\.(doc|pdf)$/i', $attr->nodeValue)) {
                echo $attr->nodeValue . 
                     " - Image is wrapped in a link to a PDF or DOC file\n";
                break;
          }

       }
}
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/dwJNAj